# Create a summary sheet based on multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have number of worksheets containing the same structure and same number of rows. Now I would like to create a master sheet to have an overview of all the worksheets using VBA.

It is like a balance sheet showing the performance over several years, which Years are on the headings and items are on rows.

Now the yearly data are put on multiple worksheets named "2012", "2013" and "2014".

Column B on sheet 1 ("2012") will be copied onto col B on "master" but for the following sheets ("2013", "2014"), data will be placed onto the next column on "master" (ie 2013 data on col C, 2014 data on col D).

I would like to have a workable macro which can count numbers of worksheets and copy paste specific data on a right column of master sheet.

Answer (score 0):

1) create in a sheet a table like that: where the first column is where the destination cell in your Master report. And the 2nd column is where the data will be copied.

[image]

2) Put all your Worksheets in a folder

3) Run this macro, which need to be placed in Master module

```
Option Explicit

'assuming that:
'- "Excel Column Code" is in column A
'- "Form Cell Code" is in column B
'in zmaster.xlsm!Sheet2


Sub UpdateData()
Dim sFile As String, sPath As String
Dim srcWbk As Workbook, dstWbk As Workbook
Dim srcWsh As Worksheet, dstWsh As Worksheet, infoWsh As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

On Error GoTo Err_UpdateData


Set dstWbk = ThisWorkbook
Set dstWsh = dstWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set infoWsh = dstWbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")

sPath = "C:\Desktop\New folder\"
sFile = Dir(sPath)
Do While Len(sFile) > 0
    If sFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
    GoTo SkipNext
    End If

    Set srcWbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)
    Set srcWsh = srcWbk.Worksheets(1)
    i = 2
    'loop through the information about copy-paste method
    Do While infoWsh.Range("A" & i) <> ""
        'get first empty row, use "Excel Column Code" to get column name
        j = GetFirstEmpty(dstWsh, infoWsh.Range("A" & i))
        'copy data from source sheet to the destination sheet
        'use "Form Cell Code" to define destination cell
        srcWsh.Range(infoWsh.Range("B" & i)).Copy dstWsh.Range(infoWsh.Range("A" & i) & j)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    srcwbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
SkipNext:
    sFile = Dir
Loop

Exit_UpdateData:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set srcWsh = Nothing
    Set dstWsh = Nothing
    Set srcWbk = Nothing
    Set dstWbk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_UpdateData:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_UpdateData
End Sub




'returns first empty row in a destination sheet based on column name
Function GetFirstEmpty(ByVal wsh As Worksheet, Optional ByVal sCol As String = "A") As Long

GetFirstEmpty = wsh.Range(sCol & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

End Function
```